# Conditions required for integral and p-series test

Tags: real-analysis

to use the integral test on a series $$\sum_{}^{} a_n$$

then if $f(n)=a_n$ and $f(x)$ is a positive continuous function and eventually decreasing then you can you the integral test. These are the conditions i found for this test, my question is does the series have to start at $n=1$ for you to apply it or can it start at any point as long as the function is positive and continuous on that interval and eventually decreasing?

Secondly, for the p-series test, to apply this does the series have to start at positive n because $1/x^p$ will be undefined when the series goes through 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The series can start at any number.  One of my calculus teachers used to say “convergence is a tail phenomenon.”  What really matters is what happens on the infinite side.  The word *eventually* in your paraphrase of the integral test is there for the same reason.
2. You can't sum a series if one of its terms is undefined, so yes, the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ must skip $n=0$.

Comment: Thanks, so can the series be eventually positive and decreasing then?

Comment: @Carlos you got it!